# Simple Chase Game Movement Using Bresenham’s Line Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, bresenham

I'm creating a game where I'm trying to use Bresenham's line algorithm(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm ) to have enemies chase a player on a 2D map. The concept of the game is similar to the one found below. The pseudo code below is from http://herselfsai.com/2007/07/simple-predator-prey-chase-algorithms.html

```
prey current position ( xp, yp )
predator current position ( xP, yP )

x = x position to move to
y = y position to move to
dx = xp – xP
dy = yp – yP
Adx = AbsoluteValue ( dx )
Ady = AbsoluteValue (dy )

if ( xp > xP ) stepX = 1 else stepX = -1
if ( yp > yP ) stepY = 1 else stepY = -1

if ( Ady > Adx ){ //the y distance from prey is larger than the x distance

fraction = 2*dx – dy;

if (( yP != yp ) && ( fraction > 0 )){
x += stepX
}

y += stepY

}else{

fraction = 2*dy – dx;

if (( xP != xp ) && ( fraction > 0 )){
   y += stepY
}

x += stepX
}
```

Enemies chase the player around the map but the it's ether in 0, 45, 90, etc degree angles and not straight line. Also, in my code the enemies also have random speed(between 0 and 5) and are sometimes over shooting the player, then trying to correct and over shoot again and again. That might be a separate issue.

I sure just not fully grasping the concept of the algorithm. What is the correct way to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You state "I sure just not fully grasping the concept of the algorithm" - So you have decided to use the algorithm on what basis? Bresenham line algorithm determines which points in an n-dimensional raster should be plotted in order to form a close approximation to a straight line between two given points. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm

Comment: @Mitch, I came across the algorithm from the website stated above. I'm looking to use the algorithm as it pertains to the code above from said website but I have a feeling the code is flawed in some way. If there is a better algorithm, I'm open to changing the code. Thanks.

Comment: I might be errantly seeing a nail here, but have you considered using the A* Algorithm? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_star

Answer (score 0):

Bresenham’s Line Algorithm is an easy to understand and easy to calculate algorithm to make your characters move through a route that's closest to eye to a straight line.

The algorithm will work for your case if cost of going 45 degrees is the same as 90 or 0 degree. Otherwise the route Bresenham takes won't be the fastest.